# Javascript simple barchart with tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some metrics to display, I need a simple barchart to show values for every day in month, and it doesn't need to have any labels or legend, when you hover the day, the data is displayed. I found this `http://codepen.io/deegill/pen/macik` which is something that I need but it cost 90$ smallest package. Does anyone have chart like this which I can use in my project?

Answer (score 2):

A set of reusable charts using D3

> http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html

Comment: My understanding is that nvd3 is undergoing a huge number of changes right now. Might not be the best solution until it's stable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make any chart I'd look at using [D3](http://d3js.org/). It's a pretty smart js framework that allows you to display data in a lot of different ways. Here is an example of it displaying a [bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579). And here is another [example](http://bl.ocks.org/anupsavvy/9513382) that uses time as the x value.

Comment: How did I forget to leave D3.js out of my answer? I'll refrain from adding it there, since you posted it as a separate answer. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

Google Charts API
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

g.Raphael.js
http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Highcharts.js (Free for non-commercial use)
http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: Upvoted for Highcharts. Free if not commercial, easy to configure, pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) for a few years now, and I have no complaints.  Might take a little effort to get started, but we use it commercially, and it's great (and free).